# sorting elements in a list in c++ without using list_name.sort()

Tags: c++, list, sorting

In this code, the right hand (rh) has unsorted numbers; and i am trying to sort

using a specific algorithm into the left hand;

Algorithm: Right hand has unsorted numbers; Left hand is to have the result (sorted numbers)

1. take the first number from the right hand into the left hand

sorting goes thus:

2. if the last number in the left hand is greater than the next number in the left hand, move one step ahead and compare
3. else insert the number from the left hand one position after the present number in the right.

e.g

lh: 5 1 3 6 7 6

rh: next lh: 1 3 6 7 9 6

rh: 5 //last position=5

next: (5>1) ==> rh: 1 5 //last position=5

next: (5>3) ==> rh: 1 3 5 //last position=5

next: (5<6) ==> rh: 1 3 5 6 //last position=6

next: (6<7) ==> rh: 1 3 5 6 7 //last position=7

next: (7<6, but 6!>6) ==> rh: 1 3 5 6 6 7 //last position=6

SORTED!!!

i googled, read some pdfs, and implemented what was shown, but i can't figure out is, am i implementing wrongly?

```
//rh= right hand
//lh= left hand
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter numbers into the left hand: ";
    list<int> rh;
    int numb;
    //Entering elements into list
    while(cin>>numb)
        rh.push_back(numb);
    //Display entered elements
        //declaring an iterator
    cout<<"You have enterred: ";
    list <int> :: iterator i;// for rh
    int t;//to get first element of rh
    for(i=rh.begin(); i!=rh.end(); i++)
    {
        cout<<*i<<" ";     
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Sorting...."<<endl;
    list <int> lh;
    list <int> :: iterator j;
    //delete the first element of rh, as it's assigned to lh
    t=*rh.begin();
    lh.push_back(t);
    rh.pop_front();
     for(i=rh.begin(); i!=rh.end(); i++)
        { list<int>:: iterator temp=lh.begin();
             for(j=lh.end(); j!=lh.begin(); j--)
            { //this is where i am not sure of
                  if(*j<*i){temp++; rh.insert(temp,*i);}
                    else
                    { //insert the value of i at the position j+1
                     //i.e insert the incoming number one position after the present one(in rh)
                         continue;
                    }
                temp++;
            }
        }
    lh.unique();//remove duplicate copies
    for(j=lh.begin(); j!=lh.end(); j++)
        cout<<*j<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"-------- !!!! DONE !!!!--------";cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit this question to make it easier to answer. I would suggest separating the explanation from the code snippet and also following the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i reformatted as requested

Comment: @n.m. Not every code that has no compilation errors or that doesn't have warnings is on-topic on Code Review. It also must be **working to the best of his knowledge**. It means that it also have to function properly. If you want to draw a line, it has to draw a line.

Comment: @n.m. please don't. CodeReview is for complete code that is working as intended. **"but i can't figure out is, am i implementing wrongly?"** is a dead giveaway that either the O.P. doesn't understand their code, or it is not working as expected. Either would make it off-topic for CR.

Comment: @Zak my understanding that it is working (didn't check it). Should have added "if working as expected", my bad.

Comment: @ n.m. That's cool. We get a lot of people pushing questions to CR from SO where it's not really appropriate, so we like to try and head things off as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to rewrite everything for you, but you're on the right track. Here are some recommendations:

1. For starters, you are going to run into problems trying to iterate through rh. What I would recommend is getting the front element, storing it somewhere (i.e. "int to_insert = rh.front()"), then deleting that element with pop_front()
2. In your for loops, you declare one of your iterators as lh.end() and then try to dereference it. lh.end() will give you an iterator off-the-end of the list, not the last element in the list, so dereferencing it will give you segfault errors.
3. Since there's no list method to get an iterator to the last element, you can change your algorithm slightly to start inserting from the beginning of lh instead of the end. If you must start from the end, use reverse iterators instead: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/rbegin/

Read up a little bit on selection sort. This is a similar sort of algorithm as what you are trying to do: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Also, on a personal note, you might find it easier to use the "auto" keyword when declaring iterators, as such:

```
// Clunky
list <int> :: iterator j;
j = lh.begin()

// Clean
auto j = lh.begin()
```

Comment: Note `auto` is a C++11 feature and will not work for older versions of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Twice the original question states that rh has the unsorted numbers, but then the example comments reverse this, showing lh with the unsorted numbers. Here is example code that does what is described, but is different than the example text and example code. Perhaps the original poster can explain what the actual goal is by stating how the below code differs from what the code is supposed to do. Note that list.insert() can be used on an empty list.

```
    list <int> lh;
    list <int> rh;
    list <int>::iterator l, r;
    rh.push_back(1);
    rh.push_back(0);
    rh.push_back(6);
    rh.push_back(7);
    rh.push_back(4);
    rh.push_back(2);
    rh.push_back(3);
    rh.push_back(5);
    while(rh.size()){
        r = rh.begin();
        for(l = lh.begin(); l != lh.end(); l++)
            if(*l > *r)
                break;
        lh.insert(l, *r);
        rh.pop_front();
    }
```